How to prove that $s>\frac{2n}{n-2}$ implies $\frac{ns}{n+2s}>\frac{2n}{n+2}$?
Let $n$ be a natural number, possibly big enough so it holds that $s>\frac{2n}{n-2}$
implies in $\frac{ns}{n+2s}>\frac{2n}{n+2}$. How to prove that one inequality implies the other?
Edit. The only possibly useful information I know about this problem is that $\frac{2n}{n-2}$ is the critical Sobolev exponent and $\frac{2n}{n+2}$ is its Hölder conjugate. This, however, only yields the inequality $\frac{s}{s-1}<\frac{2n}{n+2},$ which is totally different from what I would like to prove.

I don't understand the wording, "possibly big enough so it holds that...". What do you mean by this?

Assuming $n>2$ and $n+2s>0$,
$$\begin{align}\frac{ns}{n+2s}>\frac{2n}{n+2}&\iff\frac s{n+2s}>\frac2{n+2}\\
&\iff s(n+2)>2(n+2s)\\
&\iff sn-2s-2n>0\\
&\iff s(n-2)>2n\\
&\iff s>\frac{2n}{n-2}.\end{align}$$

$s = 2,$ $n = 1$? How are these $\iff$?

Thank you! That's what I was looking for

@DerekLuna Is it clearer now?
